# any gwt library that allow me to do cycle screenshots like instagr.am

Tags: gwt

I m working on web app in GWT, and need to implement sth like http://instagr.am/ that cycle the screenshots. any one knows what gwt library can do that? Much thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of it in Chrome's developer tools it looks like it should be pretty easy to mimic, without a library.

It looks like has a div with a background image of let's say Img1.png, containing an img tag of Img2.png. Then it slowly changes the img tag's opacity to 0, in effect hiding Img2 in favor of its background, Img1.

When it's done, it then switches the div's background image to be the one in the img tag, and picks Img3.png as the div's new background image. Continue this process forever for the effect.

It shouldn't be hard to implement this effect in GWT with a combination of `Animation` and `Style` as I've described.